# Dictionaries and Tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a dictionary with a key as a tuple and value as an int .. i.e. `x = {('G', 'N', 'L', 'C'): 4}`, how can I tell python that the first element of the key is equal to the value .. so, `'G' = 4`? Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: 1. your question doesn't make sense. What do you mean G=4? 2. If you're using python, include the python tag and you're much more likely to get responses.

Comment: Umm .. I mean, the value only applies to the first element of the key.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to form a new `dict`:

```
In [40]: x = {('G', 'N', 'L', 'C'): 4}

In [41]: y = {key[0]:val for key,val in x.iteritems()}

In [42]: y
Out[42]: {'G': 4}
```

---

Here is another way, which uses fewer Python bells-and-whistles.
First note that you can loop through the (key, value) pairs in a dict:

```
x = {('G', 'N', 'L', 'C'): 4}
for key in x:
    print(key)
    print(x[key])
```

yields

```
('G', 'N', 'L', 'C')
4
```

So, you could define a new dict which associates `'G'` with `4` like this:

```
x = {('G', 'N', 'L', 'C'): 4}
y = {}
for key in x:
    y[key[0]] = x[key]

print(y)    
# {'G': 4}
```

---

The expression `{key[0]:val for key,val in x.iteritems()}` does exactly the same thing as the for-loop above. It's called a [dict comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) (search down the page a bit for "dict comprehension").

The expression also uses the [iteritems method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems), which gives you both a key and a value on each pass through the loop, instead of just the key.

Comment: Is there a way to explain this in a more simple way? I haven't really gotten that far in my class.